# How to retrieve deleted record?

Tags: javers

I wonder how to retrieve deleted record that audited with Javers, as I know how to retrieve version changelog but when the record deleted from database table, there is no ID to retrieve audit record.

Answer (score 0):

There is no dedicated filter for selecting deleted objects snapshots.
You can use general purpose queries like [byClass()](http://javers.org/documentation/jql-examples/#by-class-query) and filter selected snapshots by `SnapshotType` on your own, although it will not be very efficient.

New `SnapshotType` filter can be easily implemented in JaVers JQL, consider contributing a PR.